# TextField Widget with emoji flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

How can I open keyboard `type == emoji`. Not number, not letter, just emoji. **Without** using `emoji_picker` package

Answer (score 2):

To open the emoji container [emoji_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker)

Create A method emojiContainer

```
 emojiContainer() {
  return EmojiPicker(
      bgColor: Colors.red,
      indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
      rows: 3,
      columns: 7,
      onEmojiSelected: (emoji, category) {
        setState(() {
          isWriting = true;
        });

        textFieldController.text = textFieldController.text + emoji.emoji;
      },
      recommendKeywords: ["face", "happy", "party", "sad"],
      numRecommended: 50,
    );
  }
```

And use an onPressed

```
onPressed: () {
                    if (!showEmojiPicker) {
                      // keyboard is visible
                      hideKeyboard();
                      showEmojiContainer();
                    } else {
                      //keyboard is hidden
                      showKeyboard();
                      hideEmojiContainer();
                    }
                  },
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I write that I don't want use ``emoji_picker`` package